# How can i create a node which will store references to a list of pictures uploaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

update: i have added the entire file

I have uploaded an image to firebase storage, i then want to send the url to firebase realtime database under a node for a particular user.

I am using this code to try it, but i get an error saying

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')
```

[image]
here is the block of code I am using

The error points to this line `                set(ref(db,'users/'+auth.currentUser.uid+'/images/'+url))

```
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { db } from "./util/firebase";
import { getDownloadURL, ref, uploadBytesResumable } from "firebase/storage";
import {storage} from './util/firebase'
import { set } from "firebase/database";
import {v4 as uuidv4} from 'uuid'

function AddPicture() {
  //const [image, setImage] = useState("");

  const auth = getAuth();
  const user = auth.currentUser;
  const metadata = {
      customMetadata:{
          'imageID': uuidv4(),
          'User': auth.currentUser.email,
      }
  }
 

  const uploadPicture = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const image = e.target[0].files[0];
    const imageRef = ref(storage,'/images/'+user.uid+'/'+image.name)
    

    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(imageRef, image,metadata);


    if (image) {
        uploadTask.on("state_changed",
        (snapshot) => {
          console.log("Uploaded image");
          console.log('current uid'+auth.currentUser.uid)

          
        },
        (error) => 
          console.log('didnt upload '+error),
        ()=>{
            getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref)
            .then((url)=>{

                set(ref(db,'users/'+auth.currentUser.uid+'/images/'),url);
                console.log(url)
            })

        }
        
        )
    }
    else {
        console.log('Please Choose an image');
        alert('image type not supported');
        return;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <form onSubmit={uploadPicture}>
        <input type="file" />
        <button >Upload</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AddPicture;
```

Answer (score 2):

As detailed in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database#set), you need to pass two parameters to the `set()` method:

- `ref`: The location to write to;
- `value`: The value to be written (string, number, boolean, object, array, or null).

In your case you pass only one parameter, the `ref` one.

You should pass the value to be written (i.e. the url), as shown below:

```
set(ref(db,'users/'+auth.currentUser.uid+'/images/'), {url: url}))
```

or

```
set(ref(db,'users/'+auth.currentUser.uid+'/images/'), url))
```

---

In the title of your question you mention "a list of pictures uploaded".

Without more details on how you get this list it is difficult to give a precise answer but you could either save an array of urls like

```
set(ref(db,'users/'+auth.currentUser.uid+'/images/'), [url1, url2]))
```

or add some extra sub-nodes like:

```
set(ref(db,'users/'+auth.currentUser.uid+'/images/0'), url1))
set(ref(db,'users/'+auth.currentUser.uid+'/images/1'), url2))
```

---

Extra note: You should also double check that `auth.currentUser.uid` has the correct value, i.e. that you call this method only when the user is [completely signed in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data).

Comment: i tried this, but i get the same error. I mean, i want to add the url to the images node each time i upload an image to firebase storage

Comment: set(ref(db,'users/'+auth.currentUser.uid+'/images/'),{image:url})

Comment: Can you debug and check the value of `auth.currentUser.uid`?

Comment: the uid matched the value of the logged in user

Comment: So you confirm that `users/'+auth.currentUser.uid+'/images/`gives a correct path? Can you try the following and tell me the output: `const r = ref(db,'users/'+auth.currentUser.uid+'/images/'); console.log(r.key); console.log(r.parent); console.log(url);`

Comment: the image folder is not created yet, i am trying to create it when i add the image url. there is no output for the code you gave, the same error has appeared, now it points to the line of code you gave as the error : const r = ref(db,'users/'+auth.currentUser.uid+'/images/');

Comment: So what is the exact value of `'users/'+auth.currentUser.uid+'/images/'`? and how do you declare `db`?

Comment: "the image folder is not created yet, i am trying to create it when i add the image url." This should not be a problem: with `ref(db,'users/'+auth.currentUser.uid+'/images/')`we are just declaring a `DatabaseReference` and when you set the value the corresponding node will be created

Comment: i declare db as: const db = getDatabase(app); // from firebase config, then i import it into uploadimage.js.   I currently have the realtime database as this : 'users/'+auth.currentUser.uid, now i want to add the images node, then inside the images node put the url for every uploaded photo

Comment: Can you try to read a simple DB node/value? See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once

Comment: so i cant read the values either, i get the same error as before, maybe i have authentication issues ?

Comment: "maybe i have authentication issues" The error message shall be different but you can indeed try to adapt yoru security rules to allow anybody to read/write to the entire RTDB ans see if it changes something.

Answer (score 0):

After getting some sleep, I realized my blunder. I was using the `ref` from `'firebase/storage'` to post to my realtime database, which has a different `ref` found in `'firebase/database'`.

```
import {ref as dbRef} from 'firebase/database';
```

I used an alias `dbref` because there is another `ref` in my file .

Once I made the changes, the original code works without errors.